# RegExp in Javascript to group items in categories

Tags: javascript, regex, grouping

I need to implement a RegExp in Javascript that allows me to match the following categories and items, associating the items to their proper category, but I don't know how:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="mycategory1.asp">text</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<div>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                </td>
                    <a href="myitem1.asp">text</a>
                <td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                </td>
                    <a href="myitem2.asp">text</a>
                <td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                </td>
                    <a href="myitem3.asp">text</a>
                <td>
            </tr>
            .....................
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="mycategory2.asp">text</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I can have more than 10 categories, and I don't know how many items will be in each category.
I could easily create a RegExp that matches me the categories and another one for the items, but how can I create a relation between them?

Thanks and best regards,

Livio

Answer (score 1):

Don't read HTML using Regexes. Give the tables classes and then read them with DOM traversal. The HTML should look like this:

```
<table class="caption">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="mycategory1.asp">text</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div>
    <table class="itemlist">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                </td>
                    <a href="myitem1.asp">text</a>
                <td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                </td>
                    <a href="myitem2.asp">text</a>
                <td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                </td>
                    <a href="myitem3.asp">text</a>
                <td>
            </tr>
            .....................
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<table class="caption">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="mycategory2.asp">text</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
...
```

Then make a list of them like this:

```
var captions = document.getElementsByClassName("caption");
var itemlists = document.getElementsByClassName("itemlist");
var items = new Array();
for (var i=0; i<captions.length; i++) {
 var categoryLink = captions[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
 var categoryItems = itemlists[i].getElementsByTagName("a");
 for (int j=0; j<categoryItems.length; j++) {
  items.push({"itemname":categoryItems[j].innerHTML,
              "itemurl":categoryItems[j].href,
              "categoryname":categoryLink.innerHTML,
              "categoryurl":categoryLink.href});
 }
}
```

Comment: I definitely am on the side of the parser advocates on this one.  That's why  I was disappointed to read that @liv913 reports that the actual HTML is not parsable by the parsing classes available.

Answer (score 0):

Regular Expressions is not the silver bullet for all the problems.. RegEx is made for text matching using patterns. IMHO this problem is better solved using any XML parser.

Comment: Given that she needs to solve the problem in javascript and it is HTML, possibly not XHTML, it is probably not a matter for an XML parser.  But your point about regex stands.

Comment: I tried to use an XML parser, but it seems that this page is not well formed and it doesn't allow to parse it...

Comment: @liv913: Sorry to hear that; it's a real-world consideration that rules out the possibility of a clean solution.  HTML/XML parsers are notoriously less permissive than actual browsers.  Permissive browsers have done a world of hurt in the name of good.